# Convert datetime for each row according to the respective timezone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am trying to figure out a way to convert the datetime for a row to it's respective timezone.

For example, Column 1 is 'user name', Column 2 is 'sent_time' in the Asia/Kolkata timezone and Column 3 is 'timezone' that records the timezone in which the user lives. Is there a way to convert all the 'sent_time' column values to their respective timezones?

Here is a sample of the data:

| User Id | sent_time | app_timezone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1610237077 | America/Los_Angeles |
| 25674 | 1610238621 | America/New_York |
| 87940 | 1610238622 | Asia/Kolkata |
| 23420 | 1610238622 | Europe/London |

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please provide a [mre]? Also, is 'sent_time' always in Asia/Kolkata tz? And since you speak of "row", are you working with a `pandas` dataframe?

Comment: Hi @MrFuppes, thank you for the response. I am using pandas and I have updated the question with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do,

```
import pandas as pd

# dummy data:
# df
#    User Id   sent_time          app_timezone
# 0     12345  1610237077  America/Los_Angeles
# 1     25674  1610238621     America/New_York
# 2     87940  1610238622         Asia/Kolkata
# 3     23420  1610238622        Europe/London

# parse Unix time to datetime, to UTC
df['sent_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sent_time'], unit='s', utc=True)

# now we can derive the time in user's tz
df['sent_time_user'] = df.apply(lambda r: r['sent_time'].tz_convert(r['app_timezone']),
                                axis=1)
```

for the dummy example, you now have

```
df['sent_time_user']
0    2021-01-09 10:34:37-08:00
1    2021-01-09 14:00:21-05:00
2    2021-01-10 00:30:22+05:30
3    2021-01-09 19:00:22+00:00
Name: sent_time_user, dtype: object
```

Further reading: [tz_localize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html) and [tz_convert](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html). Also note that you'll have to use an `apply` / `lambda` to convert all the elements of the 'sent_time' Series to individual time zones since the method only takes a scalar as argument for the target time zone.

Comment: I tweaked this code to my variables and ran it. But I'm facing 2 errors:
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
KeyError: ('sent_time', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: @user16527561 I've updated the answer; since you have UNIX time as input, I'd suggest to use unit='s' and UTC in the first step.

Comment: For the given output 2021-01-09 10:34:37-08:00, how can I split into 3 more columns: 'Date' i.e. 2021-01-09; 'Time' i.e. 10:34:37 and 'Day' i.e. Saturday

Comment: @user16527561 Do you need those to be string or date/time objects?